# Insert into a temp table is to slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, insert, temp-tables

i'd like to know why if i created a temp table out of my procedure the insert into it get slower than if i create that temp table inside my procedure.
follows an example:

```
create table #Test (col1 varchar(max))
go
create proc dbo.test
as
begin
    truncate table #Test
    insert into #Test
    select 'teste'
    FROM sys.tables
    cross join sys.columns
end
go
exec dbo.test
go

create table #Test2 (col1 varchar(max))
go
truncate table #Test2
insert into #Test2
select 'teste'
FROM sys.tables
cross join sys.columns
```

At test, we get duration 71700, reads 45220, CPU 26052
At test2, we get duration 49636, reads 45166, cpu 24960

best regards

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: why it happens. if i created a temp table out of my procedure the insert into it get slower than if i create that temp table inside my procedure.

Answer (score 1):

With logical reads and CPU being almost equal (you should run test for a number of times and get the averages to be certain), it's probably a matter of cold vs warm cache or blocking. Check physcal reads and read-aheads fro the output od `set statistics io on` to see what's going on.